# I am using MAPSVG and I am trying to use CSS to style the labels

Tags: css, svg

Here is a sample of the svg file:

```
<path id="AK" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" inkscape:label="#AK" fill="#C6C6C6" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2822" d="
```

I am trying to change the color of the label that appears on the map for Arkansas.  I have combed this and other sites and can't figure it out.

Thank you for any direction you can provide.

Comment: That looks like it is probably the path element for the state itself.  Please post the SVG for the label.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You are correct and this helped me figure it out.  The SVG for the labels did the trick.